# windows powershell curl does not recognize --data-binary @-

Tags: powershell, curl

In windows powershell, the following command results in an "Unrecognized token ..." error.

```
curl data.html |curl -H "Content-type: text/html; encoding=UTF8" --data-binary @- http://www.example.com
```

The `@-` token is not recognized.

Both powershell 7.3 and 7.4 exhibit this error.

In a Command Prompt terminal, the curl command completes as expected.

What can I do to get powershell to recognize `--data-binary @-` ?

I updated to the latest version of powershell, 7.4 from 7.3, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Try [the stop-parsing token `--%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.4#the-stop-parsing-token)?

Comment: PowerShell has _more_ [metacharacters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) (characters with special meaning) than other shells, notably including `@ { } , ; \``. For these characters to be used _verbatim_, they must be individually `\``-escaped or enclosed in a quoted string. In your case: `\`@-` or `'@-'`

Comment: In PowerShell, unlike in cmd.exe, @ and { / } are metacharacters that either require individual escaping with ` (the so-called backtick) or enclosing the entire argument in quotes: So use `@ in powershell.